# How to visualize implicit function?

Tags: functions

I have a task of visualizing implicit function: $$ y=\exp(x+y)-x-2 $$
In this function x depends on y. How can i visualize it?

Comment: I think you can solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ using the Lambert W function and some algebra tricks if that's what you want. Otherwise I'm not entirely sure what you're asking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function represents a pair of parallel straight lines !

> $e^{x+y}=x+y+2$ is equivalent to $x+y=r_0$ or $x+y=r_1$ where $r$ denotes either solution of $e^r=r+2$.